# How to get value from other table and insert the value to new table using php and oracle

Tags: php, oracle

this is my coding. the value id is from "add to basket" button. then i select form artwork then the values from artwork i want to insert it into table sales. but the insert is not function.

```
<?php
    include("dbconn.php");
    $artid =$_GET['ID'];
    $temp=oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM artwork where ARTW_ID = '$artid'");
    oci_execute ($temp);


$p = oci_fetch_assoc($temp);
    $ids = $_POST['ARTW_ID'];
    $title = $_POST['ARTW_TITLE'];
    $yy = $_POST['ARTW_YEAR'];


$price = $_POST['ARTW_PRICE'];
    $sql = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO SALE values ('".$ids."', '".$title."', '".$yy."', '".$price."')");
    header("location: checkout.php");
    exit();

?>
```